# Finding parent of parent in a where clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a restaurant that belongs to a city, which belongs to a state:

```
class Restaurant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :state
end

class State < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cities
end
```

I'd like to create a scope in the restaurant model to find the given state of the city it resides in. So far I have this:

```
scope :by_state, -> state { joins(city: :state).includes(city: [:state]).where(state: state) }
```

This unfortunately gives me the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column restaurants.state does not exist)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.where(state: state)` still queries `state` on `Restaurant`.

`scope :by_state, -> state { joins(city: :state).includes(city: [:state]).where('states.name = ?', state) }` is probably what you want.

Comment: Would I be able to simply query the id vs. the name like in my original post?

Comment: you'd have to change `states.name` to `states.id` but yes that should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The only thing with my setup is that I'm still eager loading (according to the bullet gem) despite using includes in the scope. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: what's it saying? unused?

Comment: `eager loading detected Restaurant => [:city] Add to your finder: :includes => [:city]`